# Intellij autocomplete (a function name) till names diverge and not complete to first suggestion in list

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I am trying to accomplish quick partial auto-completion in Intellij, when I am typing this:

```
line.setSt
```

I get these auto-complete suggestions:

```
setStrokeWidth
setStrokeDashOffset
setStrokeLineCap
setStrokeLineJoin
setStrokeMiterLimit
....
```

Now I wish to use auto-complete to only complete till the search results start to differ. I have no idea if there is a shortcut for this. So I wish to quickly get the auto-complete to:

```
setSt
<press something>
setStroke
```

Is this possible? This annoys me since I am so used to this in Linux terminal.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/editor-code-completion.html) there was an option to achieve that at least in IntelliJ 10 (Autocomplete common prefix), however I can't find it anymore in IntelliJ 14.(1). What version are you using?

Comment: I am (yet still) using Intellij 14.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such option in IntelliJ IDEA 14. But you can use camel hump completion and just type the letter starting the words inside the identifier that you need. For example, if you wish to choose "setStrokeMiterLimit" from the list but don't want to type the common prefix, you don't need to. All you need it just typing "M" after "setSt" (so it becomes "setSM"). Or "setSL". Uppercase is not necessary: "ssml" would match "setStrokeMiterLimit", too.